# Modal not showing labels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, pug

I implemented a modal but when I display it, it does not show any labels:

```
div#registerModal.modal.fade(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='registration-modal-title', aria-hidden='true')
  div.modal-dialog.modal-lg
    form.form-horizontal(role='form', action='/become-a-shopper', method='POST', style='margin-top: 20px;', data-action='create')
      div.modal-content
        div.modal-header  
          button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') &times;
          h4.product-modal-title 
          div.tab-content
            div#product-description.tab-pane.active
              +formFieldset('Information')(style='margin-top: 15px;')
                +formGroup(name="email", label="Email address", placeholder="Email address", true) Address
                +formGroup(name="first", label= "First", placeholder="First", true) First
                +formGroup(name="last", placeholder = "Last", true) Last
                +formGroup(name="location", placeholder = "Where can you shop?", true) Location
                +formTextarea(name="whyjoin", placeholder = "Why join?", true)(style='height: 150px;') Why join?
```

Any idea why?

I attached a picture of what I can see.